# pb with frame name in lookup_transform

Tags: python, ros-humble, tf2-ros

I've done the tutorial for tf2, and everything works fine.
Now I'm trying to reproduce the "follow" behavior with drones, but this time it fails.
I've got a Node for each drone. I do the broadcast exactly like in the tutorial and it works. At least I can see the transformation with `ros2 run tf2_ros tf2_echo cis_drone_2 cis_drone_1`

```
At time 1693834924.724220138
- Translation: [1.000, 1.000, 0.000]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, -0.000, -0.000, 1.000]
- Rotation: in RPY (radian) [0.000, -0.000, -0.000]
- Rotation: in RPY (degree) [0.000, -0.000, -0.000]
- Matrix:
  1.000  0.000 -0.000  1.000
 -0.000  1.000 -0.000  1.000
  0.000  0.000  1.000  0.000
  0.000  0.000  0.000  1.000
```

This is on startup, both drones are on the floor.
Then I start the "follow action" building the TransformListener once again like in the tutorial. Here is my callback

```py
# frames involved
from_frame = self._leader
to_frame = self.name

# Look up for the transformation between leader_frame and this mobile frame
try:
    t = self.__buffer.lookup_transform(
        to_frame,
        from_frame,
        rclpy.time.Time(),
        timeout=rclpy.duration.Duration(seconds=3.0),
    )
except TransformException as ex:
    self.get_logger().info(
        f'Could not transform {to_frame} to {from_frame}: {ex}')
    return
self.get_logger().info(f"Transform is {t}")
```

Here I get an exception :

```
Could not transform cis_drone_2 to cis_drone_1: "cis_drone_2" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist.
```

And in the terminal running `tf2_echo` I get this error :

```
Failure at 1693834935.374
Exception thrown:Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 1693834924.724220 but the earliest data is at time 1693834925.739769, when looking up transform from frame [cis_drone_1] to frame [cis_drone_2]
The current list of frames is:
Frame cis_drone_1 exists with parent warehouse_lanes.
Frame cis_drone_2 exists with parent warehouse_lanes.
```

I tried to use `0` as a value for `time` in `lookup_transform`, doc says it will get the latest, but I get this new error

```
[drone-11]   File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tf2_ros/buffer.py", line 135, in lookup_transform
[drone-11]     self.can_transform(target_frame, source_frame, time, timeout)
[drone-11]   File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tf2_ros/buffer.py", line 221, in can_transform
[drone-11]     not self.can_transform_core(target_frame, source_frame, time)[0] and
[drone-11] TypeError: time must have sec and nanosec, or nanoseconds.
```

Do I have to use the "traveling in time" to perform this "immediate" follow ?

Comment: After playing with parameters, I found that **timeout** has to be as small as possible to avoid my problem.
So my best solution is to simply do not set it which makes it to `Duration()` which is probably equal to 0 s.
Still I do not understand why it is necessary.